# How do I make both objects be like a "wall"?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on two object in `Three.js` and I enabled collision detection. So when a box intersects another it will get detected. Ok that is done but how can it be made that when either box detects collision with the other box, that box will not go through.

At the moment I have implemented a partial solution to disable `TransformControls` but it would be an impractical solution since the user might want to move the box. I have searched and tried many other solutions but I'm not finding what I really need.

I have made a screen recording and [uploaded](https://vimeo.com/906750878?share=copy) it to vimeo since stackoverflow doesn't have a video player.

This is the animation function:

```js
function animateTheeBox() {
    // Check for collision between metalBox and woodBox
    let boundsMetalBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(metalBox);
    let boundswoodBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(woodBox);
    if (boundsMetalBox.intersectsBox(boundswoodBox)) {
        // console.log("Collided, dragging disabled");
        metalBox.position.x = woodBox.position.x + 9.3;
        transformControlsMetal.position.copy(metalBox.position)
        // transformControlsMetal.enabled = false;
        orbitControls.enabled = true;
    } else {
        
        transformControlsMetal.enabled = true;
    }

    if (boundswoodBox.intersectsBox(boundsMetalBox)) {
        
        
        transformControls.enabled = false;
        orbitControls.enabled = true;
    } else {
        // woodBox.position.copy(transformControls.position)
        // transformControls.position.copy(woodBox.position)
        transformControlsMetal.enabled = true;
    }

    transformControls.setSize(70 / transformControls.worldPosition.distanceTo(camera.position) * Math.min(1.9 * Math.tan(Math.PI * camera.fov / 360) / camera.zoom, 7));
    transformControlsMetal.setSize(70 / transformControlsMetal.worldPosition.distanceTo(camera.position) * Math.min(1.9 * Math.tan(Math.PI * camera.fov / 360) / camera.zoom, 7));

    renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Box Geometry:

```
onst boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);

const woodTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(woodTextureURL);
const metalTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(metalTextureURL);

const woodBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: woodTexture });
const woodBox = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, woodBoxMaterial);

const metalMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: metalTexture });
const metalBox = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, metalMaterial);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
);

woodBox.position.set(0, 2.6, 0)
metalBox.position.set(8, 2.6, 0);

scene.add(woodBox);
scene.add(metalBox);
```

TransformControls

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const transformControls = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
transformControls.traverse(e => {
    if (e.material) {
        e.material.depthTest = true;
    }
});

let transformAnchor = new THREE.Object3D();
let bounds = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(woodBox);


transformAnchor.position.copy(bounds.min);
transformAnchor.attach(woodBox);

transformControls.attach(transformAnchor);
transformControls.setMode('translate');

const gizmo = transformControls._gizmo.gizmo;
[83, 86, 89, 91, 92, 93, 94].forEach(axis => {
    const obj = gizmo.translate.getObjectById(axis);
    obj.visible = false;
    obj.layers.disable(0);
});
scene.add(transformAnchor);
scene.add(transformControls);
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// TransformControls for metalBox
const transformControlsMetal = new TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
transformControlsMetal.traverse(e => {
    if (e.material) {
        e.material.depthTest = true;
    }
});


let transformAnchorMetal = new THREE.Object3D();

let boundsMetal = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(metalBox);
transformAnchorMetal.position.copy(boundsMetal.min);
transformAnchorMetal.attach(metalBox);

transformControlsMetal.attach(transformAnchorMetal);
transformControlsMetal.setMode('translate');

const gizmoMetal = transformControlsMetal._gizmo.gizmo;
[228, 231, 234, 236, 237, 238, 239].forEach(axisMetal => {
    const objM = gizmoMetal.translate.getObjectById(axisMetal);
    objM.visible = false;
    objM.layers.disable(0);
});
scene.add(transformAnchorMetal);
scene.add(transformControlsMetal);
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// console.log(gizmoMetal);
//---------------

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.set(50, 30, 20);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

let isDragging = false;

const orbitControls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

transformControls.addEventListener('dragging-changed', function (event) {
    orbitControls.enabled = !event.value;
    isDragging = event.value;
});

transformControlsMetal.addEventListener('dragging-changed', function (event) {
    orbitControls.enabled = !event.value;
    isDragging = event.value;
});
```

Thanks in Advance!

Edit: I have made a Pen available: https://codepen.io/rickyylow/pen/gOEXoxP

Comment: Just from an initial view of the video (without reading code), I'd guess that you calculated the collision _after_ it occured. In this case, you'd need either some mechanism to cancel the movement, or you need to calculate for the collisions _before_ the movement.

Comment: You will need to implement a more sophisticated collision response after detecting a collision.
So when a collision is detected, you need to adjust the position of the moving object so it doesn't penetrate the other object. 

This can be really challenging because it requires calculating the minimum distance needed to separate the objects without overlapping.

Comment: @DaviAmaral thanks for commenting, I tried to move the `metalBox`'s X position `+ 0.3` which looks fine but weirdly enough it works at first but then for the second time it clips through the other object.

Comment: You need log in to watch video? O_o

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Mastalerz it works fine on incognito mode.

Comment: @JugertMucoimaj I've never worked with it, I just can give you ideas... But maybe you need to look to integrating a physics engine like cannon.js or ammo.js, could be often the best approach for a fully-featured solution.    I will try to replicate it here...

Comment: @DaviAmaral thanks man! I wanted to try physics engine but I was afraid they would be incompatible with today's `Three.js` code. I will seek to implement either `ammo.js` or `cannon.js`.

Comment: @JugertMucoimaj. Keep an eye on the version compatibility between Three.js and the physics engine. If you're using the latest version of Three.js, make sure the physics library you choose is updated, with that, probably will work good.